# Switching from a textbox to a label with certain keyboard keys in a blazor server application

Tags: c#-4.0, blazor-server-side

I have the html code below. I am working on a blazor component which will allow the user to toggle from a label to an
inputbox. Once user enters text in inputbox, the display mode should now return to a label.

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control border-end-0 border rounded-pill" type="text" value="" id="example-text-input" >
                    <span>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary bg-white border-bottom-0 border rounded-pill ms-n5" type="button">
                            <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The user has a couple ways to complete the textbox and return to display mode.

1. Click the arrow button
2. Tab out of the textbox
3. Hit the enter key
4. Click anywhere else on the page where the component is rendered.

How can I write this in a Blazor server application for items 1-4 above? Some code samples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the function that processes the user input is `Process()`

```
public void Process()
{
   
}
```

Have a function that toggles between label and input control, say `ToggleMode()` in your razor component:

```
bool editing;
public void ToggleMode()
{
   editing = !editing;
}
```

Add another function called `ProcessInput()`

```
public void ProcessInput()
{
    // do validation if you want then call process.
    Process();
    ToggleMode();
}
```

Following needs to be done for your numbered requirements:

1. Add listen to onclick even on the *button* i.e. `@onclick="ProcessInput"`
2. Listen to onblur on the *input* control i.e. `@onblur="ProcessInput"`
3. Listen to onkeyup on the *input* control and then filter for enter i.e.

   void OnKeyUp(KeyboardEventArgs e)
   {
   if (e.Key == "Enter")
   {
   ProcessInput();
   }
   }
4. Same as (2), listen to onblur on the *input* control i.e. `@onblur="ProcessInput"`

your form will look like this:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto">
            <div class="input-group">
@if(editing)
{
  // show input textbox+button 
                <input class="form-control border-end-0 border rounded-pill" type="text" value="" id="example-text-input" @onblur="ProcessInput" @onkeyup="ProcessInput" >
                <span>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary bg-white border-bottom-0 border rounded-pill ms-n5" type="button" @onclick="ProcessInput">
                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
}else
{
    // show label
    <div @onclick="ToggleMode"></div>
}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It seems you are using bootstrap. If you are doing it purely for aesthetic reasons, simply toggle between the readonly plaintext and regular input. That might be a quick fix

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/form-control/#readonly-plain-text

Comment: I will try it out. So I will be using the same function ProcessInput() for all events ?

Comment: What about Clicking anywhere else on the page where the component is rendered?

Comment: "..will be using the same function ProcessInput() for all events?" that's what you need right? Note that label uses a different function

Comment: "What about Clicking anywhere else on the page where the component is rendered?" onblur will take care of it. Let me know in case it does not work.

Comment: I will do that and try it all tonight.

Comment: When you say label uses a different function what do you mean ?

Comment: // show label
    <div @onclick="ToggleMode"></div>